# Main activity to connect to existing service again

Tags: android, android-service

I have my main activity that creates a service, binds to it and start calling its method. Lets say this Activity is destroyed. The service keeps running (as it should be). Now when the activity starts again, how can I connect to the service again (and not start new one)?

What's the right way of doing it

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android services are created as singletons, so the framework will always guarantee that only 1 instance of the service is ever running, even if you call StartService 10 times in a row.

Simply run StartService and then BindService each time. If the service is already started, the StartService will simply not do anything.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answers. Is this true even if your service extend the Service class directly ( not IntentService)? Will one service always run (not 10 services)?

Comment: Yes, it also applies to the Service class. I'm currently doing this in my own projects, but if you wish to test it, simply override all service functions and see which ones get called.